# Tensorflow vgg16 prediction dramatically slow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I use vgg.h5 model + Keras (Tensorflow backend on GPU) for real-time objects classification. It works good.

Then I try to use pure tensorflow graphs with weights from vgg.h5:

1. I've parsed vgg.h5 with h5py and have received weights for all layers in numpay.array format
2. I've built a graph (I store kernels and biases in tf.Variable)
3. But I can't receive output prediction vector. After investigation I've found out that all convolutional layers work, but the first full connection layer output (fc1 with 25088 x 4096 weights matrix) in vgg16 calculated for about 5 minutes. It's not appropriate for real time classification.

So, maybe anyone has experience of building vgg16 from scratch in tensorflow and can help? Why tensorflow as Keras backend works good, but pure tensorflow (with the same weights) can't calculate full connection output? Is there any additional optimisation in Keras for realising full connection (Dense) layers?

Comment: what is the GPU/CPU load while it does the fully connected layer calculation ? What is the shape of the input to the fully connected layer (e.g. does it have a dimension which is not one while it should be one) ? Does the memory consumption rise unexpectedly ?

Comment: It's not possible to determine cpu/gpu load while FC1-layer evaluation - my pc is frozen. 
Input dimension is prepared as follow:
layer_name = 'fc1'

wd = tf.Variable(get_filter(layer_name), trainable=False, name=layer_name+'_wd')

bd = tf.Variable(get_bias(layer_name), trainable=False, name=layer_name+'_bd')

layer_shape = [-1, wd.get_shape().as_list()[0]]

fc1_flat = tf.reshape(pool5, shape=layer_shape)

fc1 = tf.nn.relu(
    tf.nn.bias_add(
        tf.matmul(fc1_flat, wd, name=layer_name), bd
    )
)

Comment: could be running out of memory because of some broadcasting. What shapes do `get_filter(layer_name)` and `get_bias(layer_name)` return ?

Comment: I have increase speed a bit by following changes:
`layer_shape = [1, fc1_wd.get_shape().as_list()[0]]`
# layer_shape = [-1, fc1_wd.get_shape().as_list()[0]]
fc1_flat = tf.reshape(pool5, shape=layer_shape)

Comment: Functions return `(25088, 4096)` and `(4096,)` numpy arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a test variant of your code, instrumented with printing shapes of tensors in several places:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # mock the previous layer's output with a placeholder
    pool5_input = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = (None,7,7,512))

    # insert a print operation to print the shape
    pool5 = tf.Print(pool5_input, [ tf.shape(pool5_input) ], "pool5 shape is ", summarize = 4)

    layer_name = 'fc1'
    wd = tf.Variable(np.ones((25088, 4096), dtype='float32'), trainable=False, name=layer_name+'_wd')
    bd = tf.Variable(np.ones((4096,), dtype='float32'), trainable=False, name=layer_name+'_bd')
    layer_shape = [-1, wd.get_shape().as_list()[0]]
    print('layer_shape:', layer_shape)

    fc1_flat = tf.reshape(pool5, shape=layer_shape)
    fc1_flat = tf.Print(fc1_flat, [ tf.shape(fc1_flat) ], "fc1_flat shape is ")

    fc1 = tf.nn.relu( tf.nn.bias_add( tf.matmul(fc1_flat, wd, name=layer_name), bd ) )
    fc1 = tf.Print(fc1, [ tf.shape(fc1) ], "fc1 shape is ")

    import time
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # evaluate network for in input of (minibatch_size, 7, 7, 512)
    minibatch_size = 32

    start = time.time()
    output = sess.run(fc1, feed_dict = { pool5_input: np.ones((minibatch_size, 7, 7, 512), dtype = 'float32')})

    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print("time to evaluate fully connected layer for minibatch size %d: %.3f seconds" % (minibatch_size, elapsed))
    print("output shape is",output.shape)
```

I get the following output:

```
layer_shape: [-1, 25088]
...: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] pool5 shape is [32 7 7 512]
...: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] fc1_flat shape is [32 25088]
...: I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] fc1 shape is [32 4096]
time to evaluate fully connected layer for minibatch size 32: 0.329 seconds
output shape is (32, 4096)
```

so for me it takes less than a second (on a GPU) for a minibatch size of 32.

You could insert similar `tf.Print()` statements into your code and verify that you have the same (or similar) dimensions. By multiplying the sizes of the dimensions you can see how much memory is used at each stage.

Comment: Thank you very much for attention for my problem. Also, I have found out new function from your code: `tf.Print()`. I will solve that problem later. It seems that huge CNN-graphs copy several times, as result: I can receive fc1-output one time, after change graph (jupyter notebook) I copy it again, and again... And after several reconstruction of graph i receive freezed PC. So I am going to solve it with Session and graphs management functions, somethimg like: `reset_default_graph()`